# Rails 3 bundler updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have an application running on thin 1.2.11 behind nginx. I was trying to update my application to the latest version of it's gems using `bundle update` on a development machine, commiting to git, then running `cap deploy`. However, thin is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.3.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

On the server I have the following gems installed system wide:

```
bundler (1.0.14)
daemons (1.1.3)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
rack (1.3.0)
rake (0.9.2)
thin (1.2.11)
```

My Gemfile for my aplication:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'thin'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I believe thin is requiring rack 1.3, while something in my Gemfile is requiring rack 1.2.3. Am I managing my gems the wrong way? What is the proper way to manage deployment and proper gem control?

I found using `bundle exec thin start` works, but I prefer a solution to allow me to use `/etc/init.d/thin start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read this: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/ before you tell us what you prefer.

Problem is you prefer to run command from gem installed into system to run application which has it's own dependencies (i.e. rack) specified in Gemfile. You can't have two version of same library loaded at the same time, so it's causing your problem with needing 'bundle exec' in from on every command.

Comment: what a great simple answer Cheers!

Comment: That's an interesting read, but I don't see how it's very helpful. Any sane Thin deployment needs to use /etc/init.d/thin start. Unless there's a way to do that, we either shouldn't be using Thin or Bundler. Also, making a particular app server a dependency of an app seems kludgy to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: @bioneuralnet Is that why you thing my answer isn't helpful? Problem is you can't start 2 Rails apps at the same time from same interpreter - probably because there are some singletons in use, you need to load some libraries in specific versions and so on, and Ruby can't cope with it (try it in Java on C#), bundler only solves managing with dependencies versioning. That's why you need to start (somehow) separate server for each app. But which server you choose is your problem, maybe there are other servers which can spawn separate Ruby process to start your application?

Comment: "/etc/init.d/thin start" does use a separate process for each app. And I agree with "which server you choose is your problem." That's why I don't think bundling Thin with an app is appropriate, because the user may want to run it with Mongrel or Passenger instead. Philosophically, it would be like bundling Nginx or a Linux kernel with a Rails app, which is clearly a bad idea.

Comment: @bioneuralnet I'm not Bundler or Thin developer, I haven't developed any of them and it's not my idea! If you have problem with it, ask your own question, maybe we can solve it. I have no problem starting Rail (2.3.x and 3.x) app with Bundler from Nginx-Passenger combo, without specifying passenger as dependency. Maybe your problem is that Thin was developed when Bundler didn't existed, and all applications used system gems, not application specific gems.

Comment: I'm merely pointing out to future readers that, in my opinion as a regular Thin user, Yehuda's article doesn't apply to this situation. It's not intended as a request for assistance or a criticism of you in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Just do `bundle exec` at start of your cap scripts and he will pickup gems from bundler.

Often I have same problem if i have in system / currently used gemset newer versions of some gems.

i even have alias called `be` in shell for `bundle exec`. New versions of rvm do bundle exec automagicly also :).